# How can i use properly our custom order in OCC(commercewebservices)?

Tags: java, spring, sap-commerce-cloud

1. In the commercewebservices, there is a placeOrder method. I would like to use our custom placeOrder. Before calling placeOrder, there are lots of custom works like new controller classes,util classes and some custom extensions (require-extension) in storefront . I do not want to copy and arrange all of things done in storefront extensions before placeOrder. What is the best suitable way to use our custom order logic and related things in OCC?
2. I have a second question about that. When I copy and arrange custom classes to OCC, I experienced an issue about acceleratorstorefrontcommons. My custom commercewebservices does not resolve acceleratorstorefrontcommons in extensioninfo of OCC. I read some contradictory about it. In help hybris, it is said that it is a special type of an AddOn but in the hybris experts website, it is said that it is not an AddOn. How can I resolve this problem?

   (https://experts.hybris.com/questions/1995/best-use-of-acceleratorstorefrontcommons-addon.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to move all classes POSSIBLE to your facades extension. Arrange the extension setup, that your configuration looks like this:

storefront -> facades <- webservices

In fact, there is this acceleratorstorefront extension which is kind of cumbersome and makes a lot of trouble. It has the folder "commonwebsrc" which content is COPIED to your storefront into the folder "commonwebsrc/acceleratorstorefrontcommons" during build and compiled there. The difference to an addon is, that it only contains java classes and no jsp/tag files.

I tried a lot but was often left with the only opportunity to copy stuff from A to B. If somebody has a better solution, I am happy to hear from it.